# How to set the width of th tag equal to the width of td tag below it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code in php. It is in footer.php. This is the code:

```
<script>
     let len = document.getElementsByTagName("th").length;

     for (let i=0; i<len; i++) {
       document.getElementsByTagName("th")[i].style.width = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].offsetWidth + "px";
     }

</script>
```

But I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined at roleaccess:1019
```

How do I fix it? Thanks everyone.

Comment: Are you sure that there are as many td tags like th tags?

Comment: `<th>` should be naturally extending to be the same side of `<td>`. Please create a [mcve] with generated HTML sample